# Python nested dataclasses ...is this valid?

Tags: python-3.7, python-dataclasses, python-class

### Background

I'm using dataclasses to create a nested data structure, that I use to represent a complex test output.

Previously I'd been creating a hierarchy by creating multiple top-level dataclasses and then using composition:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Meta:
    color: str 
    size: float

@dataclass
class Point:
    x: float
    y: float
    stuff: Meta

point1 = Point(x=5, y=-5, stuff=Meta(color='blue', size=20))
```

### Problem

I was wondering if there was a way of defining the classses in a self-contained way, rather than polluting my top-level with a bunch of lower-level classes.
So above, the definition of `Point` dataclass contains the definition of `Meta`, rather than the definition being at the top level.

### Solution?

I wondered if it's possible to use inner (dataclass) classes with a dataclass and have things all work.

So I tried this:

```
rom dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import get_type_hints


@dataclass
class Point:

    @dataclass
    class Meta:
        color: str 
        size: float

    @dataclass
    class Misc:
        elemA: bool
        elemB: int 

    x: float
    y: float
    meta: Meta
    misc: Misc


point1 = Point(x=1, y=2,
               meta=Point.Meta(color='red', size=5.5),
               misc=Point.Misc(elemA=True, elemB=-100))

print("This is the point:", point1)
print(point1.x)
print(point1.y)
print(point1.meta)
print(point1.misc)
print(point1.meta.color)
print(point1.misc.elemB)

point1.misc.elemB = 99
print(point1)
print(point1.misc.elemB)
```

This all seems to work - the print outputs all work correctly, and the assignment to a (sub) member element works as well.

You can even support defaults for nested elements:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Point:

    @dataclass
    class Meta:
        color: str = 'red'
        size: float = 10.0

    x: float
    y: float
    meta: Meta = Meta()


pt2 = Point(x=10, y=20)
print('pt2', pt2)
```

...prints out `red` and `10.0` defaults for pt2 correctly

### Question

**Is this a correct way to implement nested dataclasses?**

*(meaning it's just not lucky it works now, but would likely break in future? ...or it's just fugly and Not How You Do Things? ...or it's just Bad?)*

...It's certainly a lot cleaner and a million times easier to understand and upport than a gazillion top-level 'mini' dataclasses being composed together.

...It's also a lot easier than trying to use marshmellow or jerry-rigging a json schema to class structure model.

...It also is very simple (which I like)

Answer (score 2):

You can just use strings to annotate classes that don't exist yet:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Point:
    x: float
    y: float
    stuff: "Meta"

@dataclass
class Meta:
    color: str 
    size: float


point1 = Point(x=5, y=-5, stuff=Meta(color='blue', size=20))
```

That way, you can reorder class definitions in the way that makes most sense. Static type checkers like mypy also respect this way of forward references, which are part of [the initial pep on type annotation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references), so nothing exotic. Nesting the classes also solves the problem but is imo harder to read, [since flat is better than nested](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python).

Comment: Thanks for the info Arne. I've got to admit I'd forgotten about forward references.  I guess I'm still at a philosophical point, where you have a single element that has two attributes.  In Typescript for example this is no problem - you just make it a structure within your class: stuff: {color: str; size: float} - but in Python you can't so you've got to use composition.  But if I have a dataclass with 5 'levels' and each maybe 10 elements, I don't know if it's better to have to define 50 top-level dataclasses, just so I can at some point compose them all into a single complex one.

Comment: Coming from JS/TS to Python (newbie), even I was stumped by the complex json to dataclass conversions. In my case, I use the nested dataclass syntax as well. Unfortunately, I have a ton of keys so I have cannot specify each key; have to use hacks like assign nested to temp obj and delete from main obj then expand using (**json_obj) etc. Wish there was more elegant solution.