# Dataclass inheritance with complex fields

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I wish to use dataclasses in Python to create a base class and several derived classes. These classes will contains complex attributes, such as dictionaries. I want the derived classes to change only part of the dictionary defined by the base class, is this possible? Or am I better off with plain old classes?
Shown in the code snippet is the current situation, this seems wasteful in terms of code duplication.
In this example I could define a function that accepts a single parameter instead of the lambdas, but in a real world example I would have to define a function for every such case and that would be cumbersome.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class BaseDataClass:
    simple_field_one: int = 100
    simple_field_two: int = 200
    complex_field: dict = field(default_factory=lambda: {
        'x': 0.1,
        'y': ['a', 'b']
    })


@dataclass
class DerivedDataClass(BaseDataClass):
    simple_field_two: int = 300  # this is easy
    complex_field: dict = field(default_factory=lambda: {
        'x': 0.1,
        'y': ['a', 'c']
    })  # this is wasteful. All I changed was complex_field['y'][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be obvious, but if the change is very small it could be convenient to use `__post_init__` to apply it instead of redefining the field:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class BaseDataClass:
    simple_field_one: int = 100
    simple_field_two: int = 200
    complex_field: dict = field(default_factory=lambda: {
        'x': 0.1,
        'y': ['a', 'b']
    })


@dataclass
class DerivedDataClass(BaseDataClass):
    simple_field_two: int = 300

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.complex_field['y'][1] = 'c'
```

Slightly different alternative, in case you want to be able to control the update to `complex_field` during initialization:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, InitVar

...

@dataclass
class DerivedDataClass(BaseDataClass):
    simple_field_two: int = 300
    # having a mutable default is fine here, since its reference isn't kept around
    # and we don't change it during post_init
    complex_update: InitVar[dict] = {'y': ['a', 'c']}

    def __post_init__(self, complex_update):
        self.complex_field.update(complex_update)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use dataclasses this way quite extensively, and it seems to work quite well.

One difference I made, however, is to make the complex fields their own dataclasses (see [Python nested dataclasses ...is this valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036267/python-nested-dataclasses-is-this-valid)).

You might want to consider that approach and see how it may help you cut down some of the verbosity you're seeing.