# Nested python dataclasses with list annotations

Tags: python, json, nested, wrapper, python-dataclasses

python ^3.7. Trying to create nested dataclasses to work with complex json response. I managed to do that with creating dataclass for every level of json and using `__post_init_` to set fields as objects of other dataclasses. However that creates a lot of boilerplate code and also, there is no annotation for nested objects.

This answer helped me getting closer to the solution using wrapper:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51565863/8325015

However it does not solve it for cases where attribute is list of objects. `some_attribute: List[SomeClass]`

Here is example that resembles my data:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, is_dataclass
from typing import List
from copy import deepcopy

# decorator from the linked thread:
def nested_deco(*args, **kwargs):
    def wrapper(check_class):

        # passing class to investigate
        check_class = dataclass(check_class, **kwargs)
        o_init = check_class.__init__

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

            for name, value in kwargs.items():

                # getting field type
                ft = check_class.__annotations__.get(name, None)

                if is_dataclass(ft) and isinstance(value, dict):
                    obj = ft(**value)
                    kwargs[name] = obj
                o_init(self, *args, **kwargs)

        check_class.__init__ = __init__

        return check_class

    return wrapper(args[0]) if args else wrapper


#some dummy dataclasses to resemble my data structure

@dataclass
class IterationData:
    question1: str
    question2: str


@nested_deco
@dataclass
class IterationResult:
    name: str
    data: IterationData


@nested_deco
@dataclass
class IterationResults:
    iterations: List[IterationResult]


@dataclass
class InstanceData:
    date: str
    owner: str


@nested_deco
@dataclass
class Instance:
    data: InstanceData
    name: str


@nested_deco
@dataclass
class Result:
    status: str
    iteration_results: IterationResults


@nested_deco
@dataclass
class MergedInstance:
    instance: Instance
    result: Result


#example data

single_instance = {
    "instance": {
        "name": "example1",
        "data": {
            "date": "2021-01-01",
            "owner": "Maciek"
        }
    },
    "result": {
        "status": "complete",
        "iteration_results": [
            {
                "name": "first",
                "data": {
                    "question1": "yes",
                    "question2": "no"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

instances = [deepcopy(single_instance) for i in range(3)] #created a list just to resemble mydata
objres = [MergedInstance(**inst) for inst in instances]
```

As you will notice. `nested_deco` works perfectly for attributes of `MergedInstance` and for attribute `data` of `Instance` but it does not load `IterationResults` class on `iteration_results` of `Result`.

Is there a way to achieve it?

I attach also example with my **post_init** solution which creates objects of classes but there is no annotation of attributes:

```
@dataclass
class IterationData:
    question1: str
    question2: str


@dataclass
class IterationResult:
    name: str
    data: dict

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.data = IterationData(**self.data)


@dataclass
class InstanceData:
    date: str
    owner: str


@dataclass
class Instance:
    data: dict
    name: str

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.data = InstanceData(**self.data)


@dataclass
class Result:
    status: str
    iteration_results: list

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.iteration_results = [IterationResult(**res) for res in self.iteration_results]


@dataclass
class MergedInstance:
    instance: dict
    result: dict

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.instance = Instance(**self.instance)
        self.result = Result(**self.result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't really answer your question about the nested decorators, but my initial suggestion would be to avoid a lot of hard work for yourself by making use of libraries that have tackled this same problem before.

There are lot of well known ones like [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) which also provides data validation and is something I might recommend. If you are interested in keeping your existing `dataclass` structure and not wanting to inherit from anything, you can use libraries such as [dataclass-wizard](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html) and [dataclasses-json](https://lidatong.github.io/dataclasses-json/). The latter one offers a decorator approach which you might interest you. But ideally, the goal is to find a (efficient) JSON serialization library which already offers exactly what you need.

Here is an example using the `dataclass-wizard` library with minimal changes needed (no need to inherit from a mixin class). Note that I had to modify your input JSON object slightly, as it didn't exactly match the dataclass schema otherwise. But otherwise, it looks like it should work as expected. I've also removed `copy.deepcopy`, as that's a bit slower and we don't need it (the helper functions won't directly modify the `dict` objects anyway, which is simple enough to test)

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List

from dataclass_wizard import fromlist


@dataclass
class IterationData:
    question1: str
    question2: str


@dataclass
class IterationResult:
    name: str
    data: IterationData


@dataclass
class IterationResults:
    iterations: List[IterationResult]


@dataclass
class InstanceData:
    date: str
    owner: str


@dataclass
class Instance:
    data: InstanceData
    name: str


@dataclass
class Result:
    status: str
    iteration_results: IterationResults


@dataclass
class MergedInstance:
    instance: Instance
    result: Result


single_instance = {
    "instance": {
        "name": "example1",
        "data": {
            "date": "2021-01-01",
            "owner": "Maciek"
        }
    },
    "result": {
        "status": "complete",
        "iteration_results": {
            # Notice i've changed this here - previously syntax was invalid (this was
            # a list)
            "iterations": [
                {
                    "name": "first",
                    "data": {
                        "question1": "yes",
                        "question2": "no"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

instances = [single_instance for i in range(3)]  # created a list just to resemble mydata

objres = fromlist(MergedInstance, instances)

for obj in objres:
    print(obj)
```

Using the `dataclasses-json` library:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List

from dataclasses_json import dataclass_json


# Same as above
...

@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class MergedInstance:
    instance: Instance
    result: Result


single_instance = {...}

instances = [single_instance for i in range(3)]  # created a list just to resemble mydata

objres = [MergedInstance.from_dict(inst) for inst in instances]

for obj in objres:
    print(obj)
```

---

**Bonus:** Let's say you are calling an API that returns you a complex JSON response, such as the one above. If you want to convert this JSON response to a dataclass schema, normally you'll have to write it out by hand, which can be a bit tiresome if the structure of the JSON is especially complex.

Wouldn't it be cool if there was a way to simplify the generation of a nested dataclass structure? The `dataclass-wizard` library comes with a CLI tool that accepts an arbitrary JSON input, so it should certainly be doable to auto-generate a dataclass schema given such an input.

Assume you have these contents in a `testing.json` file:

```
{
    "instance": {
        "name": "example1",
        "data": {
            "date": "2021-01-01",
            "owner": "Maciek"
        }
    },
    "result": {
        "status": "complete",
        "iteration_results": {
            "iterations": [
                {
                    "name": "first",
                    "data": {
                        "question1": "yes",
                        "question2": "no"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Then we run the following command:

```sh
wiz gs testing testing
```

And the contents of our new `testing.py` file:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import date
from typing import List, Union

from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard


@dataclass
class Data(JSONWizard):
    """
    Data dataclass

    """
    instance: 'Instance'
    result: 'Result'


@dataclass
class Instance:
    """
    Instance dataclass

    """
    name: str
    data: 'Data'


@dataclass
class Data:
    """
    Data dataclass

    """
    date: date
    owner: str


@dataclass
class Result:
    """
    Result dataclass

    """
    status: str
    iteration_results: 'IterationResults'


@dataclass
class IterationResults:
    """
    IterationResults dataclass

    """
    iterations: List['Iteration']


@dataclass
class Iteration:
    """
    Iteration dataclass

    """
    name: str
    data: 'Data'


@dataclass
class Data:
    """
    Data dataclass

    """
    question1: Union[bool, str]
    question2: Union[bool, str]
```

That appears to more or less match the same nested dataclass  structure from the original question, and best of all we didn't need to write any of the code ourselves!

However, there's a minor problem - because of some duplicate JSON keys, we end up with three data classes named `Data`. So I've went ahead and renamed them to `Data1`, `Data2`, and `Data3` for uniqueness. And then we can do a quick test to confirm that we're able to load the same JSON data into our new dataclass schema:

```py
import json
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import date
from typing import List, Union

from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard


@dataclass
class Data1(JSONWizard):
    """
    Data dataclass

    """
    instance: 'Instance'
    result: 'Result'


@dataclass
class Instance:
    """
    Instance dataclass

    """
    name: str
    data: 'Data2'


@dataclass
class Data2:
    """
    Data dataclass

    """
    date: date
    owner: str


@dataclass
class Result:
    """
    Result dataclass

    """
    status: str
    iteration_results: 'IterationResults'


@dataclass
class IterationResults:
    """
    IterationResults dataclass

    """
    iterations: List['Iteration']


@dataclass
class Iteration:
    """
    Iteration dataclass

    """
    name: str
    data: 'Data3'


@dataclass
class Data3:
    """
    Data dataclass

    """
    question1: Union[bool, str]
    question2: Union[bool, str]


# ---- Start of our test

with open('testing.json') as in_file:
    d = json.load(in_file)

c = Data1.from_dict(d)

print(repr(c))
# Data1(instance=Instance(name='example1', data=Data2(date=datetime.date(2021, 1, 1), owner='Maciek')), result=Result(status='complete', iteration_results=IterationResults(iterations=[Iteration(name='first', data=Data3(question1='yes', question2='no'))])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [dacite](https://github.com/konradhalas/dacite) `from_dict`. This is what you need in order to handle **nested** dataclass.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dacite import from_dict


@dataclass
class User:
    name: str
    age: int
    is_active: bool


data = {
    'name': 'John',
    'age': 30,
    'is_active': True,
}

user = from_dict(data_class=User, data=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can actually nest dataclasses directly in a definition, and it works fairly well.  Take a look at a post of mine where I was trying to solve a similiar problem a while back: [Python nested dataclasses ...is this valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036267/python-nested-dataclasses-is-this-valid)

Or you can define a 'child' dataclass, and have that as the type of an element in a 'parent' container dataclass.

I still use this approach in production code today, and it works well (I also use dataclasses-json, as someone mentioned, for json serialisation and also do validation of consistency.

I also twisted nested dataclasses to allow exporting of **json-schemas**, based on their definitions.  ...not simple but do-able.  (For our use case - exporting data for import by NodeJS application, a json schema was necessary).

---

**However** as the first reply mentioned, there is a better approach (likely in your case) - which is to use **pydantic**.  I'd recommend if you're starting almost from scratch to go with that.

It's on my list of to-do's for our production code to re-factor it to use pydantic instead of nested dataclasses:  nested dataclasses do work, and you can get them to do json serialisation and self-validation against they're defined typing.   ...but it's a bit of a pain IMHO.

This is what pydantic was designed to do, and (again IMHO) does it a lot simpler and cleaner out of the box.

Comment: agreed, `pydantic` is a good solution, however the only problem as I remember was mentioned somewhere is that it introduces package bloat - for ex. you might not need validations or even a replacement for dataclasses. I also like `dataclasses-json` for what it provides as well as good docs, however it's important to note that it introduces other 3rd party dependencies you might not need (for ex. marshmallow) and as a result it's slower than pydantic. I would suggest pydantic over dataclasses-json if given a choice personally - in case it wasn't obvious I'm not a fan of marshmallow in general.